# Writing the following sql in active record / arel DB agnostic way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I got the following sql expression

> g.date > CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1' day * t.notice_days

it works on postgres and as raw sql via my app, Is there an elegant Active Record / AREL way to write the same expression?

Comment: Can you give a little more context. What tables/models are `g` and `t`? Are you doing a join to bring `t` into the query?

Comment: g and t are table name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the Integer version of `t.notice_days` and `G` is a model you should just be able to do:

```
future_time = t.notice_days.days.from_now
g.where("data > ?", future_time)
```

also you can set future_time as `Time.now + t.notice_days.days`

Comment: t.notice_days is a column name, different for each row.